# Popping to specific ViewController in NavigationController stack

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have set up a NavigationController programmatically in my SceneDelegate. My app logic requires at a certain stage to go back to a specific ViewController on the stack. The problem is that when I do this with `popToViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) -> [UIViewController]?`, I seem to loose track of the NavigationController – there is no Back button available even though I did not pop back to the root controller.

When I am in the ViewController in question, my NavigationController's ViewControllers' stack looks like this:

```
(lldb) po navigationController?.viewControllers
▿ Optional<Array<UIViewController>>
  ▿ some : 4 elements
    ▿ 0 : <Vocabulary.MainViewController: 0x7fbd4570dcd0>
    ▿ 1 : <Vocabulary.VocabularyViewController: 0x7fbd4566ce80>
    ▿ 2 : <Vocabulary.LearnViewController: 0x7fbd45532180>
    ▿ 3 : <Vocabulary.LearnResultViewController: 0x7fbd4569f900>

(lldb) po mainNavigationController.viewControllers
▿ 4 elements
  ▿ 0 : <Vocabulary.MainViewController: 0x7fbd4570dcd0>
  ▿ 1 : <Vocabulary.VocabularyViewController: 0x7fbd4566ce80>
  ▿ 2 : <Vocabulary.LearnViewController: 0x7fbd45532180>
  ▿ 3 : <Vocabulary.LearnResultViewController: 0x7fbd4569f900>
```

I now pop back to `navigationController.viewControllers[1]` in `LearnResultViewController` like so:

```swift
override func willMove(toParent parent: UIViewController?) {
        if let _ =  mainNavigationController.topViewController?.isKind(of: LearnResultViewController.self) {
            if isPresenting {
                if let vocabularyViewController = mainNavigationController.viewControllers.first(where: { $0 is VocabularyViewController} ) {
                    mainNavigationController.popToViewController(vocabularyViewController, animated: true)
                    //navigationController?.popToViewController(vocabularyViewController, animated: true) //same behavior
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

`isPresenting` is just a flag I set in `LearnViewController` in `viewDidLoad` cause `willMove` is called when entering `LearnViewController` already and obviously I only want to pop when leaving and `mainNavigationController` is a global variable right now (mainly cause I thought it should be global so that it can be referenced from anywhere which did not help so far...).

Now when I do hit the back button, **I can get back to `VocabularyViewController`, but I don't have a Back button any more there – so the stack of my NavigationController seem to be lost.**

While still in `willMove` I can see that `LearnResultViewController.navigationController` becomes `nil` – which causes my problem. Above mentioned `mainNavigationController` still has the state by then, but the "local" `navigationController becomes`nil:

```
(lldb) po mainNavigationController.viewControllers
▿ 2 elements
  ▿ 0 : <Vocabulary.MainViewController: 0x7fbd4570dcd0>
  ▿ 1 : <Vocabulary.VocabularyViewController: 0x7fbd4566ce80>

(lldb) po navigationController?.viewControllers
nil

(lldb) po navigationController
nil
```

What can I do to just get back to the desired ViewController while keeping my stack / state in my NavigationController? Is there another approach I should take?

To be quite frank I don't even understand why the scene's navigationController is set to nil in the first place...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your approach, and it really doesn't work.

You should remove LearnViewController from your navigation stack in LearnResultViewController.

```
navigationController?.viewControllers.removeAll(where: { $0 is LearnViewController })
```

After that, when you hit the back button, you will get back to VocabularyViewController. And the back button will be there.

You shouldn't override willMove for that.

Comment: Awesome – works like a charm! To clarify: I am now just running mentioned code in `viewDidLoad` of `LearnResultViewController`.

By removing the unwanted `LearnViewController` prior to popping, I can pop back to the desired `VocabularyViewController` (which gives an overview of words rather than the interface to learn them again).

Thanks for your help, Vladislav!

Answer (score 0):

for swift 4.0

```html
for controller in self.navigationController!.viewControllers as Array {
        if controller.isKind(of: DashboardVC.self) {
            _ =  self.navigationController!.popToViewController(controller, animated: true)
            break
        }
    }
```

for swift 3

```html
let viewControllers: [UIViewController] = self.navigationController!.viewControllers
for aViewController in viewControllers {
    if aViewController is YourViewController {
        self.navigationController!.popToViewController(aViewController, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, but it doesn't solve my issue... I am getting back an instance of the destination viewController already and am successfully popping back to it – but when I do so, the viewController is not embedded in the __navigationController__ any more...